# Bridges on A Virtual Host

Tags: rhel, kvm, bridge, libvirt

Years ago, I set up a virtual host on RHEL 7 with 2 NICs talking to 2 different LANs.  I used some combination of `brctl`, `ifconfig`, etc.  The host has guests on both LANs.  The guests and external hosts on LAN1 should be able to connect to the host.  However, there is no reason for the anyone on LAN2 to connect to the host.  All traffic from the host to LAN2 should go through an external switch & firewall.

```
------  x.x.1.17   LAN1   x.x.1.1----
host |___________________________| switch
     |             LAN2   x.x.2.1|
     |___________________________|
------                           ---
```

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.3448edf46b6c       no              em1
br2             8000.3448edf46b6e       no              em3
# ifconfig br0
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 172.16.3.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.3.255
ether 34:48:ed:f4:6b:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
# ifconfig br2
br2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
ether 34:48:ed:f4:6b:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
# arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
172.16.3.24              ether   52:54:00:91:66:93   C                     br0
172.16.3.16              ether   52:54:00:48:3d:2b   C                     br0
169.254.16.161                   (incomplete)                              br0
172.16.3.21              ether   52:54:00:1d:a4:c7   C                     br0
169.254.208.171                  (incomplete)                              br0
172.16.3.1               ether   00:0e:da:b6:f9:bd   C                     br0
172.16.3.17              ether   00:25:90:d9:c5:b1   C                     br0
172.16.3.15              ether   52:54:00:a2:b6:c0   C                     br0
169.254.239.170                  (incomplete)                              br0
traceroute to 172.16.2.3 (172.16.2.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  gw-gr (172.16.3.1)  0.903 ms  0.833 ms  0.771 ms
2  huginn (172.16.2.3)  1.636 ms  1.611 ms  1.579 ms
```

I am trying to move the guests to a virtual host on RHEL 8 since 7 is going EOL.  I got the LAN1 bridge & nic configured.  The host can't get to the LAN2 bridge & nic working without assigning an IP to the bridge.  And, if I do that, traffic from the host to LAN2 bypasses the switch/firewall & directly goes out the second nic to LAN2.

```
# nmcli con add type bridge con-name dmz ifname br1
# nmcli con add type ethrnet slave-type bridge con-name enp7s0 ifname enp7s0 master dmz
# nmcli con add type ethernet slave-type bridge con-name enp7s0 ifname enp7s0 master dmz
# nmcli connection up dmz
Connection successfully activated (master waiting for slaves) (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/155)
# nmcli connection show
NAME    UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
dmz     21130c23-08ff-4737-b485-b2d51e75e2fb  bridge    br1
br0     1c4bda58-a889-44de-9ae4-815dbac5a31d  bridge    br0
eno1    6d58a4e3-486e-44b3-aa7d-485b75aa50af  ethernet  eno1
enp7s0  64225181-c3eb-4acd-bc0c-25b32ae244ac  ethernet  enp7s0
# nmcli device status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE                                  CONNECTION
br0     bridge    connected                              br0
eno1    ethernet  connected                              eno1
enp7s0  ethernet  connected                              enp7s0
br1     bridge    connecting (getting IP configuration)  dmz
```

I think the second nic needs to be put in promiscuous mode.  But, I can't figure out how to do that with `nmcli` or `firewall-cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands will set up a bridge for virtual guests without having to assign an IP address to the bridge.

```
# nmcli con add type bridge con-name dmz ifname br1
# nmcli con add type ethernet slave-type bridge con-name lan2 ifname enp7s0 master br1
# nmcli con modify dmz ipv4.method disabled
# nmcli con modify dmz ipv6.method disable
# nmcli con modify dmz 802-3-ethernet.accept-all-mac-addresses true
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=dmz --change-interface=enp7s0
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=dmz --change-interface=dmz
```